# Windows sendTo Context Menu for Adobe AIR?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, filesystems, adobe

I would like to know, if there is any way to enable the following (at least in windows):

right-click on any file in local filesystem, choose sendTo and send the file to an adobe air application (for upload purpose for example).
AIR can handle that via INVOKE Event, but how can I achieve this from the windows side - how can an AIR application register itself as a sendTo Option?

any chance to achieve this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the way to do this would be to write a bat file that modifies the windows registry to include a hook for your application.

Looks like this is the process, I'm sure there is a way to automate this (sorry, I can't help here, I'm not familiar with any windows api's)

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: Thanks for your link,  but this treats a way to add something to the desktop context menu. furthermore, im not so sure (but may be), if AIR is allowed to write some bat files for windows registry. i hope, there is a more easy way just to access the sendTo folder on windows explorer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sendTo folder but AIR can execute a .bat file that will in turn write to the windows registry. See this thread: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/662058