# Can we add menu option in OS folder right click menu Using Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4, flash-cs5

I am working on Adobe AIR project, in which I need to add "menu option" in a menu, which opens when we right click on any folder. I want to ask that can it be done using adobe air?

Details:
Here is more detail: I want to develop air application whose function will be to upload the file/folders on ftp server. It start at OS startup (automatically) and run in background. I want to add menu item "Upload" in OS folder/file right click menu, so that whenever i click on that folder that file/folder should be upload on FTP server. Hope you got it. I've done FTP part, but I want to know that can I add menu item in menu which opens when we right click on any file/folder.

Comment: You need to provide more details and/or some code. Are you "opening" these "folders" inside of a custom file browser that is part of your application??? Have you never heard of a ContextMenu item? http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3contextmenu/

Comment: Okay that makes the issue much clearer... you should edit your question and add this extra detail to it, rather than post it as a comment. :)

Comment: There was question similar to yours, maybe it will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044027/windows-sendto-context-menu-for-adobe-air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly in AS3 because such things are done via registering server on the OS via DLL (at least on Windows) like GIT installation does or by directly modyfing the
the system registry.

You can find more informations [here](http://www.jfitz.com/tips/rclick_custom.html)

I'm afraid you'll have to do a small installer with another langage in addition to your AIR application.

Hope that helps.